I Have a Question About the Laplace Inverse Transformation Process.
The equation that needs to be inverse transformed[1]
$$
\frac{s + (s + 1)(s^2 + 1)}{(s^2 + 1)(s^2 + 2s + 2)}
$$
The modified equation 1 for the Laplace inverse transformation[2]
$$
\frac{s^3 + s^2 + 2s + 1}{(s^2 + 1)(s^2 + 2s + 2)}
$$
The modified equation 2 for the Laplace inverse transformation[3]
$$
\frac{s}{(s^2 + 1)(s^2 + 2s + 2)} + \frac{s + 1}{(s + 1)^2 + 1}
$$
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/wjdiyFNY.png
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/TM6gcM4J.png
[3]: https://i.sstatic.net/Tp95BwyJ.png
Why do the values from the second and third methods differ, and which method is the correct one?

$$\dfrac{s + (s + 1)(s^2 + 1)}{(s^2 + 1)(s^2 + 2s + 2)} =\dfrac{s^3+s^2+2 s+1}{\left(s^2+1\right) \left(s^2+2 s+2\right)} = \dfrac{s+2}{5 \left(s^2+1\right)}+\dfrac{4 s+1}{5 \left(s^2+2 s+2\right)}$$ Find a common denominator and then combine to show the relation is correct that the RHS = LHS.
